# Display data from multiple nodes in Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I am trying to display data from multiple nodes in my database on a listview.

[image: This is the layout of my database.] What I'm trying to do is display the "detailCategory" and "detailValue" for every type of workout, every time its saved.

Here is the database reference i'm currently using for my app.

```
currentUserDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("WorkoutDetails").child("Cardio").child(currentUId);
```

I know this needs to increment into the further nodes, but i'm not sure how to read from multiple nodes from at one time.

I'm using dataSnapshot to read the data. I have data being read by specific date in another page, using the code below. So  the problem might just be with the database reference in this case.

```
 @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    currentUserDB.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            cardiosList.clear();

            for(DataSnapshot cardioHistorySnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Cardio cardio = cardioHistorySnapshot.getValue(Cardio.class);

                cardiosList.add(cardio);
            }

            CardioHistoryList adapter = new CardioHistoryList(Cardio_History.this, cardiosList);
            ListViewCardioHistory.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is detailCategory and detailValue?  Can you show what your database structure is like?

Comment: in the first one, "detailCaregory" is Running and "detailValue" is 11, its what the user can enter in another page

Comment: Sure, and how are they structured in your database please edit your question to help us understand what your database is like.

Comment: It looks like you're already iterating the children and converting them to an object.  What is not working the way you expect in your sample?

Comment: right now, its only going as far as the date node. So i can display the date. But, I need to iterate through the id, type of workout(Running/Swimming) and then the detail underneath. How can i make it so it will read just the "detailCategory" and the "detailValue" from every date and id.

Answer (score 0):

As I saw in your comment, that you are "going as far as the date node", according to this, to display the `detailCategory` and the `detailValue`, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference dateRef = rootRef.child("WorkoutDetails").child("Cardio").child(currentUId).child(date);
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot dSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String detailCategory = ds.child("detailCategory").getValue(String.class);
                String detailValue = ds.child("detailValue").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", detailCategory + " / " + detailValue);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
dateRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Where the `date` is the date under the `currentUId`, which can be `1-3-2018`, `2-3-2018` and so on. And as you can see, to achieve this, we needed to use nested queries.